# Animating from within classes in Actionscript 3 (Not on the timeline), what's the best way?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, animation

I've found some stuff online about how to animate in actionscript 3 from within a class, but haven't been able to find a really good tutorial. I want to control the animations from a class because at some point I intend to move from the flash IDE to using flash develop, where I won't have access to the Flash IDE's timeline.

I have to be able to control an **initial animation** (opening a bag) which joins onto an **animation loop** (searching through a bag).

The only way I have been able to do this so far is to add an event listener to listen for the initial animation's final frame. Then when initialAnimation.currentFrameLabel = "Last" then I gotoAndStop("animationLoop").

This has been working fine, if a bit time-consuming. I'm just wondering if there's a better, easier way to do it? Can anyone tell me or point me towards a tutorial that does it better? Thanks very much!
Romano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend instead of using an event listener, you use the method addFrameScript. Essentially you can fire a method when a specific frame number is reached.

Read the following question for more information.
[actionscript3 whats the point of addFrameScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536357/actionscript3-whats-the-point-of-addframescript)

Comment: This is great and looks like the right answer to my question, thanks! I didn't mention in my question that I would also be porting my game to Starling, which I just found out apparently does not do addFrameScript - just to let anyone know who's in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what it is you want to do:

Usually if you are working together with an artist or want to do animations that are non-code driven, the "best way" is usually to listen for something to happen, and then start animations  and on last frame of animation (or when you want to return control to code) you create an event, or use a callback or something else to let code notify that animation is complete or reached a certain point.

If you want to do something from code, the easiest way is to use an external animation library.

- Tweener (https://code.google.com/p/tweener/)
- TweenLite (http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/)

Using those libraries, you would write something similar to:

```
function fadeOut():void {
    mc.alpha = 1;
    Tweener.addTween(mc, {alpha:0, time:0.275, delay:1, onComplete:onDone});
}

function onDone():void {
    trace("Animation finished");
}
```