# Play only a certain range of frames

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a combobox on the stage and changing its value I want to play only a certain range of frames:

```
stop();

combo01.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, change);

function change(event:Event):void{
    if (combo01.selectedItem.label == "BAL"){
        gotoAndPlay(50);
        if (currentFrame == 99) {stop();}

    }
}
```

The game is not stopped but returned to frame 1.

Comment: Why do you have everything in one time line if you only want to play parts of it. split it into individual MovieClips, then display the right MovieClip.

Answer (score 0):

You want your current frame check to happen when frame 99 is reached, not when change() is called. One way you can do this is to add a listener to check each frame as it is entered by the timeline until it reaches your desired frame:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
function checkFrame(e:Event):void {
    if(currentFrame == 99){
        stop();
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
    }
}
```

Another way is to use the undocumented (but long supported) addFrameScript(): [actionscript3 whats the point of addFrameScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536357/actionscript3-whats-the-point-of-addframescript)

You could also just put a conditional stop() on frame 99, such as `if (stopFrame == 99) stop()`, then simply set `stopFrame` in your change handler.

You get the idea. You need your check to happen at frame 99.